# I am new to RegEx and need help pulling a string (sku) within a string in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

The string is delimited by underscores and it could be as simple as taking the seventh _ and pulling the `SKU` from there. Ideally there would be a way of finding the text that looks like a SKU and pulling that out in tableau. I can't seem to figure out how to actually execute this.

```
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Apparel_Hoodies_SMZM1047XL_160x600
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Apparel_Hoodies_SMZM1047XXL_160x600
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Apparel_Hoodies_SMZM1047XXL_300x250
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Apparel_Hoodies_SMZM1047XXL_728x90
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Sunglass_Lifestyle_DFPPBRMT_300x250
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Sunglass_Lifestyle_DFPPBRMT_728x90
Client_RT_Sample_PRODUCT_Men_Sunglass_Lifestyle_DFRPGNMB_300x250
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning the string between the 5th and 6th Spaces in a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835535/returning-the-string-between-the-5th-and-6th-spaces-in-a-string)

Comment: At least run a quick search before asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is an Excel or CSV file this is really easy with Tableau 9. In the Data Connection window click the arrow next column and select split or custom split. The latter will break it into as many separate fields as you want.